# The usage of [lasso] is a regression

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I just realized that the [lasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lasso) tag is mostly used for [lasso regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)), while the tag description states:

> "Lasso is an interpreted programming language and server for
>   developing database-driven web applications."

And indeed, there is a [Lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(programming_language)) programming language.

What should be done about this?

Comment: Is there a [lasso-regression] tag?

Comment: @JL2210 Apparently not.

Comment: There are also lots of questions related to [LA SSO](https://lasso.entrouvert.org/). This needs some effort. I'll try to post my findings on this either today night or early tomorrow morning.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks. I suppose we can create more descriptive tags and retag, but last time I retagged more than a few questions (on MSE), I got some (well deserved) angry comments about polluting the active questions. Better to ask here first :) If there is any way I can help...

Comment: That's a good move, asking on meta before doing anything is always the best. Don't worry much about retagging for now, you can always join us once you have 2k rep. We'll take care of it, eventually.

Comment: Turns out it isn't that bad. My earlier statement about having "lots of questions" related to LA SSO, is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the [lasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lasso) tag definitely needs a disambiguation. My proposal here is to

1. Retag all the non Lasso regression related posts (as mentioned below)
2. Save the tag wiki and excerpt of [lasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lasso).
3. Rename the tag to [lasso-regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lasso-regression), and update the wiki.

For retagging the posts, I checked the questions, and it seems like there is a need for some manual retagging. Specifically [these 56 questions that don't seem to be related to Lasso Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5blasso%5d%20-%5bregression%5d%20%20-%5br%5d%20-%5bglmnet%5d%20-%5bmachine-learning%5d%20-%5bscikit-learn%5d%20-%22regressions%22%20-%22regression%22%20is%3aq&mixed=0). There are questions about:

- Obviously Lasso Language, which need to be retagged to [lasso-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lasso-lang). We can reuse the old excerpt and wiki here.
- Lasso.js module builder for JavaScript, https://github.com/lasso-js/lasso, which need to be retagged to [lasso.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lasso.js).
- D3.js Lasso pluggin - https://github.com/skokenes/D3-Lasso-Plugin. There are a significant number of questions related to this. We might require a [d3.js-lasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js-lasso) tag for this, or just use [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js). I would err on the side of creating a new tag.
- A question related to Liberty Alliance SSO (or LA SSO), [SAML logout Error : ProfileUnsupportedProfileError : <ProfileUnsupportedProfileError(-409): Unsupported protocol profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55649550/saml-logout-error-profileunsupportedprofileerror-profileunsupportedprofilee), where we can just probably drop the tag.

Given that there are just above 50 posts, I guess this shouldn't take more than 30 minutes of time, for a 2k user to go through. Once that is done, we can move ahead with renaming the tag.

Comment: I went over the questions in your selection query retagging most of them.  2 exceptionally bad ones have CVs pending; all the others do appear to be about regression of some sort or another.  I have tag wiki's with edits pending on the [d3.js-lasso] and [lasso-lang] tags; otherwise it's ready for you to rename the original tag.

Comment: @Dan, drowsy eyes here ... but I can't see a usage guidance in the excerpts that you have suggested. Apart from that everything seems fine, thanks for your work.

Comment: The guidance shows as a separate edit from the main body to me, for a total of 4 edits for the two wikis; someone (I assume you) approved 1 of the 4.  https://imgur.com/a/8CoZSSK

Comment: Not sure if the pending links on my profile will help find them for approval, if so:  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23750020 https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23750021  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23749964

Comment: I saw them ... in the excerpt, you need to add a note about when exactly you need to use or not use the tag. Anyway, I'll get back to you in chat after a few minutes.